# Link errors when using calcOpticalFlowPyrLK function to do optical flow in Opencv

Tags: opencv, graphics

I have tried to write a program to test optical flow using opencv, but when it's linking it gives this error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(class  
cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const  
&,class cv::_OutputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray
const &,class cv::Size_<int>,int,class cv::TermCriteria,double,int,double)" (?
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK@cv@@YAXABV_InputArray@1@00ABV_OutputArray@1@11V?
$Size_@H@1@HVTermCriteria@1@NHN@Z) referenced in function _main 
E:\Documents\Projects\VisualStudio\LKMethod2\LKMethod2\main.obj
```

Usually it is because that the link libraries haven't been included, but this time I have include these opencv's libraries in Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies, like below:

```
C:\sdks\opencv\build\x86\vc11\lib\Release\opencv_calib3d244.lib
...
...
C:\sdks\opencv\build\x86\vc11\install\lib\opencv_video244.lib
C:\sdks\opencv\build\x86\vc11\install\lib\opencv_videostab244.lib
```

And the most strange thing is that only this calcOpticalFlowPyrLK function has link error while other functions do not have such error.(But indeed I have included the opencv_video).
I have tried to rebuilt the opencv libraries, but in vain.
Please help me solve it, thx.

Comment: it may be a opencv 244 bug? It is still a beta. did you try to use opencv 243 instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

- `opencv_calib3d244d.lib` instead `opencv_calib3d244.lib`
- `opencv_video244d.lib` instead `opencv_video244.lib`
- `pencv_videostab244d.lib` instead `pencv_videostab244.lib`